# WebDeploy gets Unauthorized error while deploying via remote Web Deployment Agent

Tags: webdeploy

I have a remote server (Win2008R2) with WebDeploy 3.0 installed on it. Web Management Service isn't installed on it (actually I tried to install it but it cannot be contacted due to closed ports on my side).
I'm trying to deploy a package (zip) to the server via local WebDeploy 3.0 tool.

> Server.deploy.cmd /T /M:myserver.no-ip.org "/U:myserver\Administrator" "/P:pwd" /A:Basic

I tried both Basic and NTLM auth methods.

I'm getting error:
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN
More Information: Connected to 'myserver.no-ip.org' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'myserver.no-ip.org'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Error count: 1.

Please note that I'm actually connectin to WebDeploy Agent Service not Web Management Service. That's important as there are tons of info how to setup WMSrc with WebDeploy.

I know that WebDeploy Agent only supports connecting as Administrator. That is my case - I'm specifying the remote server Administrator credentials.
I tried to open WDAgentSrc url in the browser. I was promted for creditials and they were accepted.
I checked "Microsoft Web Deploy" log in the Event viewer - it's empty.

How to get it working?

Comment: Have you tried a user that's in the Administraors group but is not "Administrartor"?

Comment: Yes, I specifically created "admin" user which is in the Administrator group. No luck.